# Contradiction impedance match using transformer

Tags: impedance

[image]

The transformer doesn't change the power. However, if the impedance mismatch, there will be power loss on the load side. Is it contradictory?

Comment: There will always be some power loss.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not contradictory. The impedance of the load is reflected back to the source as the impedance times the square of the turns ratio.

Assume a 1:1 ratio, 50 \$\Omega\$ source resistance and 50 \$\Omega\$ load. The square of the turns ratio is 1, so the source sees a 50 \$\Omega\$ load, the current in the primary is the source voltage divided by 50 \$\Omega\$ + 50 \$\Omega\$, and maximum power transfer is achieved.

If the load was changed to 100 \$\Omega\$ the source would now see that 100 \$\Omega\$, the current in the primary is the source voltage divided by 50 \$\Omega\$ + 100 \$\Omega\$, and the power in both the source side of the transformer and load side would be less. This is where I think you may be confused, the power in both the primary and secondary will be approximately the same, and changing one changes the other.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt explanation! It is really helpful!

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for my related problem? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/642107/what-is-the-power-being-set-on-power-supply-work Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The power input to the primary is always equal to the load power (assuming an ideal transformer).

The impedance seen by Zs is equal to ZL multiplied by the square of the turns ratio. If ZL was adjusted in value to make the impedance seen by Zs equal to Zs then there is maximum power transfer. Now if we adjust ZL away from this maximum power transfer value, the power in ZL reduces but at all times the power input to the primary is still equal to the load power.

Adjusting ZL to make ZL times the square of the turns ratio equal to Zs gives maximum power transfer, 50% of the power is dissipated in Zs and 50% is dissipated in ZL and so at maximum power transfer the efficiency is 50%.

There is no contradiction.

Comment: James, thanks so much for your detailed explanation! It clears my confusion!

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for my related problem? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/642107/what-is-the-power-being-set-on-power-supply-work Many thanks!