# What is the power being set on power supply?

Tags: power-supply

[image: Ultrasonic welding power supply]

The picture is the inside of the power supply of the ultrasonic welding machine, model Sonobond MH-2016. The source has an output impedance of 50 Ω and a transformer for impedance matching. It has a control mode of power and energy.

For example, I set up 3000 W and 1500 J. The machine will stop when 1500 J is achieved. Here is my experiment data: it took 1 s to achieve 1500 J. That means the power is 1500 J/1 s = 1500 W, even though I set 3000 W.

Interestingly when the setting is 1000 W-1500 J, it just takes 1.5 s to achieve 1000 J. That means the real power is the same as the setting for 1000 W.

I don't know if the power I set is the total power or the power for the load, and I can't figure out how the voltage and current react to the setting. Is rhe voltage or the current constant during the loading, or changing randomly?

Comment: You have not  revealed to us the model of the machine you are referring to. It sounds like you need to contact the manufacturer with your question.

Comment: Kartman, thanks for the comments! It is Sonobond MH-2016. Yes, I am trying to contact the electrical engineer of the company but haven't received a response yet.

Answer (score 3):

The Sonobond MH-2016 is a 1500 W Ultrasonic spot welder.

> What is the power being set on the power supply?

It's the RF power limit for the job.

**Case 1:**

***Set values***

***RF power limit = 3000 W***

***Energy = 1500 J***

The rated power output is 1500 W. Hence only 1500 W  is applied for 1 s.

The RF power limit is not exceeded.

**Case 2:**

***Set values***

***RF power limit = 1000 W***

***Energy = 1500 J***

1000 W is applied for 1.5 s.

The RF power limit is not exceeded.

Comment: @ vu2nan, thanks for the comment! The power limit is 3500 W. What does this power limit mean? Is the maximum power transferred to the load? If you design a power supply that can set the power, what will you define this power?

Comment: Hi Alex, It means that the RF power output of the generator should not exceed the limit value set for that weld.

Comment: Okay, I see. From the maximum power transfer theorem, the load impedance should match the output impedance, right?

Comment: Yes. An impedance matching network in the generator takes care of that.